# does ViewResult contains response?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

if we look at ViewResult object returned by action method, ViewResult implements ActionResult(implements IActionResult) as

```
public class ViewResult : ActionResult
{
  ...
  public override Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context); 
}
```

`ExecuteResultAsync` seems to be the guy that generates responses.

But I always get told that it is Razor converts CSHTML files into C# classes, compiles them, and then creates new instances each time a view is required to generate a result. Below is the C# class that Razor creates for the Index.cshtml view

```
public class ASPV_Views_Home_Index_cshtml : RazorPage<string[]> {
   ...
   public override async Task ExecuteAsync() {
      WriteLiteral(@"<!DOCTYPE html><html><head> ...
   }
}
```

so `ExecuteAsync` also seems to generate responses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When [`ViewResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewresult?view=aspnetcore-2.2)  gets executed by the framework (i.e. calling [`ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewresult.executeresultasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ViewResult_ExecuteResultAsync_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ActionContext_)
  ), it is responsible for 1. creating the [`IView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.razorview?view=aspnetcore-2.2) that represents the correct cshtml files (view and layout) and 2. feeding this information to the [`IViewEngine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.razorviewengine?view=aspnetcore-2.2). The view engine is the one responsible for compiling and writing the page contents to the output stream (i.e. calling [`IRazorPage.ExecuteAsync Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.irazorpage.executeasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Razor_IRazorPage_ExecuteAsync)).

So, the `ViewResult` just loads everything it needs, and in the end, `IRazorPage.ExecuteAsync` is the one who truly writes to the output stream.